# Abuse of notation : same function name for different distributions

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability, hierarchical-bayesian, notation

##### Is this too much of an abuse of notation to use **the same letter**, e.g. $f$, to designate the joint - $f(x,y)$, marginal - $f(x), f(y)$, and conditional - $f(x|y), f(y|x)$ - probability/cumulative density functions throughout a paper, relying on always mentioning the arguments?

There is a tradition of usingthe same letter $\mathbb{P}$ to designate all sorts of probability, conditional and joint alike, but what about the density functions? Your experience and all references to sources discussing the issue will be much appreciated!

##### Example :

Let $\theta, x, y$ be the random variables with the following data generating process :

- $\theta \sim N(0,1),$
- $ x = \theta + u $ where $u \sim N(0,2)$
- $ y = \theta + v $ where $v \sim N(0,3)$

I rely heavily on the usage of following objects :

- $f(\theta) = \phi(\theta)$, $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}})$, $f(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4}}\phi(\frac{x}{\sqrt{4}})$ - marginal p.d.f.'s
- $f(x|\theta) = \phi(x - \theta)$ - density of conditional distribution of $x$ given $\theta$ (*likelihood*)
- $f(x,y,\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^3}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}x & y &\theta \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}2 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 & 1\\1 & 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}^{-1} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ \theta \end{bmatrix} \right)$ - joint p.d.f.

Comment: I don't like it, but I have rarely complained because usually the context and the syntactic roles of the symbols make their meanings clear.  However, when you rely on such information, you had better be *absolutely correct* and make no typographical errors!  Ultimately you need to make a trade-off in your considerations for your readers: abbreviated notation reduces typographical clutter and turgid formulas, whereas detailed notation often supplies enough redundancy and clarity to survive many typographical errors.

Comment: @whuber Very much appreciated, thank you!!